# Change backcolor with radio buttons using switch-case only

Tags: c#, radio-button, switch-statement

I'm a beginner for C# and i have a home work. In the form, i have a groupbox with 5 radio button and numeric up/down for days. When i change the num. up-down, backcolor should change its color which selected before. I can only use switch-case. I managed the num. up-down, a label changes with it. But i can not insert the switch-case for color change. Actually i can't name the switch.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Pazartesi";


        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte sayi = Convert.ToByte(numericUpDown1.Value);


            switch (sayi)
            {
                case 1:
                    label1.Text="Pazartesi";
                    switch ( )
                    {
                        case renkbtn_1.Checked:
                            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
                            break;
                        case renkbtn_2.Checked:
                            this.BackColor = Color.White;
                            break;
                        case renkbtn_3.Checked:
                            this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                            break;
                        case renkbtn_4.Checked:
                            this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                            break;
                        case renkbtn_5.Checked:
                            this.BackColor = Color.Green;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    label1.Text="Salı";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    label1.Text = "Çarşamba";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    label1.Text = "Perşembe";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    label1.Text = "Cuma";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    label1.Text = "Cumartesi";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    label1.Text = "Pazar";
                    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

The switch statement doesn't work that way.

Inside the braces in that `switch ( )` should be an expression that results in some value (it's *not* a 'name' but might be a single variable).
Those `case`s must have (compile time) constants, that are checked against the value from the switch expression.

You will have to rewrite it to a bunch of `if` statements:

```
  if (renkbtn_1.Checked)
      this.BackColor = Color.Red;
  else if (renkbtn_2.Checked)
      this.BackColor = Color.White;
  else if (renkbtn_3.Checked)
      this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
  else if (renkbtn_4.Checked)
      this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
  else if (renkbtn_5.Checked)
      this.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

Comment: My understanding is that he needs to do that only using switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, you change the up-down value, you want to set the backcolor to whatever is the color of the radiobutton you selected. Right?

If that's the case, you'll have to get which radiobutton is checked and then set the color correctly.

Then you can iterate through the controls of your groupbox to get the checked radio:

```
foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
                {
                    RadioButton rb = c as RadioButton;
                    if (rb.Checked)
                    {
                       //here you can either store the checked radio button in a variable to further check the color you need to set, or do the logic here.
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Your whole code could be like this:

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Pazartesi";

```
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte sayi = Convert.ToByte(numericUpDown1.Value);


        switch (sayi)
        {
            case 1:
                label1.Text="Pazartesi";
                break;
            case 2:
                label1.Text="Salı";
                break;
            case 3:
                label1.Text = "Çarşamba";
                break;
            case 4:
                label1.Text = "Perşembe";
                break;
            case 5:
                label1.Text = "Cuma";
                break;
            case 6:
                label1.Text = "Cumartesi";
                break;
            case 7:
                label1.Text = "Pazar";
                break;
        }
        RadioButton selectedRadio = GetSelectedRadioButton();

        switch(selectedRadio.Name)
        { 
           case rankbtn_1.Name:
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
           case rankbtn_2.Name:
                this.BackColor = Color.White;
                break;

           //Repeat for the other buttons.
        }

   }

   private RadioButton GetSelectedRadioButton()
   {
                foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
                {
                    RadioButton rb = c as RadioButton;
                    if (rb.Checked)
                    {
                       return rb;
                    }
                }
            }
   }
```